# D3 time range drops the first month

Tags: javascript, d3.js

In the library `D3`. I find the set of functions to handle dates a bit inconsistent. For example, doing the following 4 steps in a console of a page loading `D3` I get:

```
> start = new Date(2010, 11, 30)
Thu Dec 30 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
> end = new Date(2011, 0, 2)
Sun Jan 02 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)
> d3.time.months(start, end, 1)
[Sat Jan 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)]
> d3.time.days(start, end, 1)
[Thu Dec 30 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), Fri Dec 31 2010 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time), Sat Jan 01 2011 00:00:00 GMT+0000 (GMT Standard Time)]
```

the above indicates that `day.range` starts from the first item and ends just before the second, while `month.range` seems to do the opposite.

In the [documentation](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Intervals) it's stated:

```
# d3.time.months(start, stop[, step])

Alias for d3.time.month.range. Returns the month boundaries (e.g., January 01)
after or equal to start and before stop. If step is specified, then every step'th
month will be returned, based on the month of the year. For example, a step of 3
will return January, April, July, etc.
```

`after or equal to start and before stop` is also mentioned for `time.days` but the result appears to be different. Also, when these functions return after and when equal to the start? What makes the difference?

**NB:** my wish would be having these functions returning arrays of days, months, years including **both** start and end parameters.

Comment: You should open an [issue](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues) about this.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff thanks again for replying. I wasn't sure for about having a real issue. I'll follow your suggestion. thanks

Comment: It's a feature request kind of thing, so it definitely belongs there :)

Comment: @LarsKotthoff [done](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1596) Yeah I agree, it's not a bug. The documentation is pretty clear about `months` behaviour. but I think it should allow including the "ends" of the range anyway.

Answer (score 0):

As clearly explained in [here](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/issues/1596) the behaviour is in fact consistent. Both `day.range` and `month.range` aim to return each daily and monthly boundaries between the `start` and `end` parameter.